# Ошибка при вставке новой записи в базу данных через Entity Framework при наличии начальных данных

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

Генерируется база данных с начальными данными.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<Chair>().HasData(
        new Chair[]
        {
            new Chair {Id = 1, Name = "ПМИ" },
            new Chair {Id = 2, Name = "АСОИУ" },
            new Chair {Id = 3, Name = "ИЯ" },
            new Chair {Id = 4, Name = "СИБ" }
        });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ChairConfiguration());
    }
}

public class ChairConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Chair>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Chair> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        builder.Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Потом в программе считывается файл, где может оказаться, что нет необходимой записи в базе данных, тогда ее туда нужно добавить.

```
private int GetChairIndex(string chairName)
{
        using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            if (db.Chairs.Where(c => c.Name == chairName).ToList().Count() == 0)
            {
                var chair = new Chair(chairName);
                db.Chairs.Add(chair);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return db.Chairs.Where(c => c.Name == chairName).Single().Id;
        }
}
```

На этом этапе выскакивает исключение из-за повторения ключа (Id). Причем при первом запуске происходит попытка новой записи присвоить Id = 1, при каждом следующем запуске Id увеличивается каким-то магическим образом. В итоге, на пятой попытке происходит успешное добавление. Почему Entity Framework сразу не может понять, какой Id нужно присвоить новой записи?

Класс Chair:

```
public class Chair
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    public List<Discipline> Disciplines { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    public Chair()
    {
        Rooms = new List<Room>();
        Disciplines = new List<Discipline>();
        Groups = new List<Group>();
    }

    public Chair(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Rooms = new List<Room>();
        Disciplines = new List<Discipline>();
        Groups = new List<Group>();
    }

    public Chair(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Rooms = new List<Room>();
        Disciplines = new List<Discipline>();
        Groups = new List<Group>();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        Chair c = (Chair)obj;
        return (this.Id == c.Id && this.Name == c.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: `db.Chairs.Where(c => c.Name == chairName).ToList().Count() == 0` — жесть, откройте для себя `Any`. Либо сразу делайте `var chair = ...SingleOrDefault`, а потом проверяйте на null, тогда из метода и вернуть можно будет `chait.Id`. Ну а по сути вопроса — просто не надо указывать Id при добавлении данных самостоятельно, оставьте это на откуп БД, это на 100% ее задача. Ну и следует рассмотреть вопрос о том, чтобы у сущности Chair сделать первичным ключом Name

Comment: @АндрейNOP Конструктор класса нам не показан, но почти уверен, что там всё ок, т.к. незаполненный id по дефолту будет 0 и это норм. А вот почему автоинкремент не применяется - это загадка. В приведённом коде ничего об этом нет. Возможно и правда стоит не вставлять id при создании, но как-то некрасиво. А если нужно seed'ить данные с пропусками?

Comment: @АндрейNOP HasData требует, чтобы первичный ключ был задан, разве нет?

Comment: @AK, что значит "с пропусками"? Никакую логику на Id нельзя завязывать.

Comment: @Halva, ага, судя по всему — да, показывайте в таком случае код сущности Chair

Comment: @АндрейNOP я имею ввиду сценарий, когда в базу вставляется id = 1,2,3,4 а потом удаляется id = 3. Можно такую ситуацию смоделировать когда делаете seed базы.

Comment: код класса Chair добавил.

Comment: Мне не удалось воспроизвести проблему. Создайте пустой проект и попробуйте воспроизвести на минимально возможном коде. Иначе пока помочь невозможно.

Comment: @АндрейNOP не знаю, зачем я так сделал. наверное, я ввел в некоторое заблуждение, указав в тегах entity framework, а не entity framework core, с которым я на самом деле работаю. https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/value-generation.html - прочитал это, но builder.Property(c => c.Id).UseNpgsqlIdentityColumn(); не помогает.

Comment: Да я понял, что EF Core, еще то что у вас PostgreSql может иметь значение

Comment: А нельзя использовать GUID вместо Int для ключей?

Comment: @XelaNimed можно, но узнал об их существовании я только сейчас. так что останусь с int, думаю, потому что не до правок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение проблемы оказалось интересным и спорным, указано оно здесь: https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/367

Предлагается два способа:

1. Вставлять начальные данные с отрицательными индексами;

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Chair>().HasData(
            new Chair[]
            {
                new Chair {Id = -1, Name = "ПМИ" },
                new Chair {Id = -2, Name = "АСОИУ" },
                new Chair {Id = -3, Name = "ИЯ" },
                new Chair {Id = -4, Name = "СИБ" }
            });
```

2. При инициализации базы данных начинать индексацию с определенного значения. В моем случае с 5, так как 4 записи уже вставлены.

```
            modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("ChairsIds")
                .StartsAt(5);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Chair>()
                        .Property(c => c.Id)
                        .HasDefaultValueSql("nextval('\"ChairsIds\"')");
```

Comment: Ага, т.е дело всё-таки в провайдере Postgre, поэтому у меня на MS SQL не воспроизводилось

Comment: @АндрейNOP забавно, что исправлять, видимо, это они не собираются, несмотря на то, что эти решения не кажутся интуитивными.